# How to convert a multiple column table into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, analysis

Name    Age    Grade

Jacob    10    60

John     11    75

Matt     13    81

If the above were a text file in notepad, how would I convert this into a dictionary of the form:

```
{'Jacob':{ 'Age': '10', 'Grade': 60}, 'John':{'Age': '11', 'Grade': 75}, 'Matt': {'Age': '13', 'Grade': 81}}
```

In python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. And please...no screeenshots.  Lastly, you need to demonstrate the code you've written to address your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using regular expression groups

```
import re

# Read File into variable 
file = "Name Age Grade Jacob 10 60 John 11 75 Matt 13 81"

# Match Name, age, Grade
pattern = re.compile(r'([A-z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)')

# Create Dictionary Placeholder
dictionary = {}

# For each match split groups into separate vars
for name, age, grade in re.findall(pattern, file):

    # Add To Dictionary
    dictionary[name] = {
        'Age':age,
        'Grade':grade
    }

print(dictionary)
```

Outputs

```
{'Jacob': {'Age': '10', 'Grade': '60'}, 'John': {'Age': '11', 'Grade': '75'}, 'Matt': {'Age': '13', 'Grade': '81'}}
```

To read text into variable

```
file = open('textdocument.txt', 'r').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The part you are probably missing is the splitting of lines based on whitespace.

```
data = {}
with open('textfile') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        name, age, grade = line.split()
        data[name] = { 'age': age, 'grade': grade}
```